# How to pass argument to form in updateview?

Tags: python, django

I want to use UpdateView in my model Event. This model had this field:

```
employee = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='event_employee')
```

My view :

```
class UpdateEvent(UpdateView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'dashboard/pro_update_event.html'
    form_class = UpdateEventForm
    other_variable = None

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(UpdateEvent, self).get_form_kwargs()
        names_clients = User.objects.filter(professionnels=self.request.user)
        kwargs.update({'names_clients': names_clients})
        return kwargs

    def get_success_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse_lazy('pro_details_event', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

My Form :

```
class UpdateEventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    edit an event
    """
    class Meta():
        model = Event
        fields = ('employee', 'date_start', 'date_end')

    def __init__(self, names_clients, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpdateEventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['employee'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=tuple([(client.pk,client.last_name.capitalize()+" "+client.first_name.capitalize()) for client in names_clients]))
```

It seems work, the widget "select" contain the correct values. 
example : `<option value="2">Dupond Jean</option>`

But when I submit the form :
Cannot assign "'2'": "Event.employee" must be a "User" instance.

I don't understand because if remove "get_form_kwargs" in my view and "def **init**" in my form, the value passed is the same (the pk of the employee). It's works with this way.
But the problem is all employee are selectable and the username is display not the firstname and lastname.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `employee` `ForeignKey` on your Event model points to the `User` model, but you're populating the choice field for the `employee` field with `Particulier` model data.

Either change the foreign key to point to the `Particulier` model, or pass in `Users` to the form kwargs

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I forgot to fix this error in the code in this page.

But I have the error in my 1st comment, with populating the choice field with an User model data.